# docker-compose no such service: myapp

Tags: docker

I've run an image with: 'docker-compose up'

With 'docker ps' i get:

```
CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
55e1fd18acf1        simpleappnodedocker_web   "node app.js"            6 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds        0.0.0.0:9000->3000/tcp   myapp
9879ff20e241        postgres:9.6              "docker-entrypoint..."   36 hours ago        Up 36 hours         0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   nd-db
```

I try run the bash to enter to the shell, but i get an error, how to solve this, i thinking i'm doing something wrong.

```
$docker-compose run myapp /bin/bash   
ERROR: No such service: myapp
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: myapp
    build: .
    command: node app.js
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
```

Comment: you are very definitely doing something wrong. To help you, I would need to know what you did and how you did it. Please post your docker-compose.yaml and a complete recall of all your steps.

Comment: it's working with: docker exec -it myapp /bin/bash

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann you have the yml config, but really need use docker-compose run, if i can do it with docker run?

Comment: nope, you don't. but it is a great tool to have the config in a git repo for example

Comment: so, where is the erro?

Comment: Ahh, now I get it, I think. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think you got the relation of `docker` and `docker-compose` wrong:

`docker-compose` is a wrapper around `docker`. To do its job `docker-compose` needs its config: `docker-compose.yaml`

**Spinning your example further:**

create *docker-compose.yaml*:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    container_name: myapp
    build: .
    command: node app.js
    ports:
      - "9000:3000"
```

use `docker-compose` to start the container and run a command in the running container:

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose exec web /bin/bash
```

`docker-compose` uses the name of the service - in your case this is `web` - whereas `docker` uses the container name - in this case `myapp`.

So to run `/bin/bash` through `docker`, you would use the following:

```
docker exec -ti myapp /bin/bash
```

you could remove the `container_name` from `docker-compose.yaml`, then the container would be named automatically by `docker-compose` - similar to the service, but prefixed with the name of the `docker-compose` stack (the foldername where `docker-compose.yaml` is located).

Comment: You can specify the `docker-compose` yaml file with : `docker-compose -f docker-compose-custom.yml`

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is right but somehow was a bit confusing in its broad explanation on "the relation of docker and docker-compose".

The main thing to get rid of the error in question is to do what the error says: "ERROR: No such service:", therefore, you *must* choose a service that is in your compose file, and *not* the container name. In the example, it is `web`, and NOT `myapp`.

In your case, do not run

```
docker-compose run --rm myapp bash
```

but run

```
docker-compose run --rm web bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you're running the command in the same folder than your docker-compose.yml, otherwise you'll get the same error message but Phillip's answer above won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ... use the service tag, not your chosen container name, as mentioned in the answer by questionto42standswithUkraine

I also had this issue, because I had 5 different flavours of my docker-compose.yml file, called docker-compose1/2/3/4/5.yml.  Each of them had the same service names, just the environment definitions were different between them.

docker-compose logs would ***only work*** if I supplied the config file I had used to run the the system up.

so

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-3.yml -d
```

needed

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-3.yml logs <service-name>
```

to work